# String : Replace function with expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, replace

A string representing a currency is to be converted to a number.
For example:

```
Input : "125.632.454.454.403,51"
Output expected : 125632454454403.51
```

Currently I am trying:

**Trial 1)**

```
a = "125.632.454.454.403,51";
a.replace(/./, '');
```

> Result = "25.632.454.454.403,51"

**Trial 2)**

```
a = "125.632.454.454.403,51";
a.replace(/./g, '');
```

> Result = ""

But I expect the replace function to find all the occurrences of "." and replace by "".

**Trial 3)**

```
a = "125.632.454.454.403,51";
a.replace(/,/, '');
```

> Result = "125.632.454.454.40351"

I would be glad if I find a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\.` instead of `.`. The **[dot (`.`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)** matches a single character, without caring what that character is. Also you can do it with single **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with callback .

```js
var str = "125.632.454.454.403,51";

str = str.replace(/\.|,/g, function(m) {
  return m == '.' ? '' : '.'
});

document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```js
var str = "125.632.454.454.403,51" ;
var result = str.replace(/\./g,'').replace(/\,/g,'.');

console.log(Number(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` *returns* the changed string, it does not change it in-place!

You can find this out, by refering to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var Result = a.split('.').join("");

console.log(Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` has specific meaning in a regex. It matches any character. You need to escape the dot if you are actually looking for the character itself

```
var a = "125.632.454.454.403,51";
var result = a.replace(/\./g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `(parseFloat(a.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,""))/100)`
And if you have to do this for multiple currencies, I would recommend looking into autonumeric.js. It handles all this for you.